# Why is an answer with a link to a commercial product un-acceptable?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416864/how-to-add-customer-email-to-order-grid-in-magento-1-4/22756048#22756048) has an answer that I thought was fairly useful. That answer is now hidden because it got flagged for deletion.

Could a moderator please look at the answer and explain why it is considered inappropriate? The author shares a link that has a software component/plugin for download, but there is also a bona fide attempt at answering the question, so what gives?

Comment: It got flagged as spam and deleted by a moderator.

Comment: Why is it considered spam though? It was attempting to answer the question, no?

Comment: I can't say for sure. But it definitely falls along the lines of somebody dropping a link to their product. A moderator can say more on this.

Comment: £29.99 for a solution.

Comment: @Mysticial Why can't someone link to their product if it's relevant to the question and actually attempts to answer it?

Comment: @JasonSturges Since when does SO only allows links to free products?

Comment: @ArmanH [Limits for self-promotion in answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Looking at the user's [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3443846/user3443846?tab=answers), almost all of them are identical with a link to a product.

It's clear that the user's sole purpose on the site is to advertise that product. (Even the user's profile is an advertisement.)

That constitutes spamming. Don't be surprised if more of the user's answers get deleted.

Comment: Ah, great, didn't look at the rest of answers. Now that makes sense. However, in principle, it is acceptable to link to own website if it contains relevant info/product/software?

Comment: Yes, it's okay to link to site/product. But only in moderation. If more than say 10% of your posts are self-promotional, that's crossing the line.

Comment: FWIW, I have 6 answers with a link to my website. But that's out of 800+. So not a problem.

Comment: @ArmanH - Yeah, in this case 10/11 of their answers linked to their for-pay product. Also, this was at least the fourth account they've used to spam these products, so we were primed to remove this. We also see a *lot* of spam around Magento questions, for some reason, so we're a little more sensitive about promotional answers there.

Comment: @BradLarson One more... http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/18382